# How do I print all contents after finding path to key using jq?

Tags: json, select, command-line-interface, jq

```
{
  "A": "B",
  "?": {
    "x" : "y",
    "D" : "F",
    "G" : "U"
  }
}
```

Since I don't know the key (?), I'm able to use this jq command

jq '.. | .x? | select(.)'

to locate .x & print its contents , but what do I do if I want to print all contents inside ??

Comment: The question is not very clear.  Are you asking: given a string, K, find the object containing a key named K, and print all its values?

Comment: @user9186277, it looks like might like then the `jtc` tool as well - it allows traversing JSON tree upwards (from found elements) - exactly what you ask here! E.g. your query would look like this: `jtc -w'<x>l[-1][:]'`, where lexeme `[-1]` actually goes 1 tier up (from the recursively found label `x` in `<x>l`) and then lists all the nested children (`[:]`). PS. I'm the developer of the `jtc` tool.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless (non-commercial) plug.

For unknown files
I have an approach that generates
*all* distinct `jq` query paths in a `.json` file
and presents them in `jq`'s format

perfect for exploring & pasting back into your queries

https://github.com/TomConlin/json_to_paths

Answer (score 0):

With your input, the following jq filter produces the output shown below:

```
. as $in
| paths as $p 
| $p
| select($p[-1] == "x")
| $in
| getpath($p[:-2])[]
```

#### Output

```
"y"
"F"
"U"
```